# Scala best practice : Option[Error]

Tags: scala

I have a method wich return a `Option[Error]`... Is that a good practice in Scala ?

Should I use a `Either[Error, Unit]` instead ? Or something else ?

```
def canCreateUser(user: String): Option[ErrorMessage] = {
//code
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Try[Unit]` seems the most appropriate IMHO. It is meant to encapsulate an Exception and has nice recovery features

Comment: Judging from the name `canCreateUser`, it should have return type `Boolean`.

Comment: All the options mentioned look good to me as long as it is consistent with the rest of the project. You can go for Boolean if it is a simple case. If you want to return custom errors then Try[Unit] or Option[ErrorMessage] also look good.

Comment: @BrunoGrieder If you're going to return a `Try`, you might as well return a more useful type than `Try[Unit]`, e.g. a `Try[String]` (whose successful variant would be `Success(user)`)

Comment: @Jubobs Yes I agree as @nmat mentions, the most important thing I believe is to be consistent in the choice the encapsulating monad to make chaining using `for` comprehensions easier

Comment: Judging from the name a `Try[Boolean]` looks the best choice.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh It depends. If all combinations of output (`Success(true)`, `Success(false)`, `Failure(...)`) make some sense in the OP's problem, then I could be convinced. Otherwise, no.

Comment: `Try[String]` seems to be nice. I will try it. The advantage of `Option[ErrorMessage]` was to just continue the treatment if the method returns `None` and to have a custom error message if there is an error. Thank you all :)